# Nuxtlj when user refresh,back,close show popup if click refresh or close fire method

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to my Nuxtjs application when user click refresh or back or close window to show pop up 'Changes made you may not save' and if click refresh or close to the pop up run a method.

If click cancel i want nothing happens!

My point of view is this function to add an event Listener in mounted method and if user click some of this to run a method only if user Refresh or close tab or close window or back button!

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.reset)
```

I want to know how can i realize that user click refresh or close in the pop up to run a method

Comment: I don't know what your talking about here. Some code or [repro] could actually be useful.

Comment: It is simple i want when user click in browser refresh or back button or close button to show a pop up and say 'Are you sure you want to exit, refresh what ever user clicked'
Yes or No if user click yes i want to run a method If user click No nothing happens!

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: So far i made a method to preventDefault behevior when a user click the refresh button or close or back button and ask him are you sure you want to refresh and if user click yes there i want to run a code!